# Пакет и ключ приложения

Tags: android, package, key

Простенький вроде вопрос. Я же смогу обновлять свое приложение в GP, если создам новый проект с тем же пакетом и выберу тот же ключ подписи ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Да сможешь, ток не забудь VersionCode поднять

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Человек в данном запросе явно хотел полуить краткий ответ, а не эссе на тему того что да как работает)